# carrierwave doesn't have public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails-4, with cloud9 IDE

[image]

I wana use carrierwave to upload images however if I install gem ,
it is nothing change.it can not have images doesn't show up public/uploads/products

[image]

how should I do for in this case ?

Comment: What happens when you're trying to upload an image? What do you see in your server logs (`log/development.log`) file?

Comment: Please don't paste images or image links: they do not allow us to cut-and-paste code in case we want to point out some errors or issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a case of installing the gem - you need to setup all of your access rights and point your application to the S3 buckets that you've set up:

http://lifesforlearning.com/uploading-images-with-carrierwave-to-s3-on-rails/

If you follow that guide then it should help you.

Comment: Btw, it's possible to use a local file system for file storage. S3 eventually isn't cost-free.

Comment: Good point - but I don't think the user has done any of the config needed in the first place

Comment: Thank you for your support! now it'fine !!